# Can we override methods in WCF or web services?

Tags: wcf, web-services

I want to know if we can override WCF methods or web service methods. If so, then how?

Answer (score 1):

Try this for overloading WCF service methods

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyCalculator
 {
        [OperationContract(Name="AddFloats")]
        float Add(float operand1, float operand2);

        [OperationContract(Name="AddIntegers")]
        int Add(int operand1,int operand2);
 }
```

Comment: While the answer is correct, you should explain that in the generated contract it is not possible to have overloads hence specifying different operation names.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but my question is about override not overload.

Answer (score 0):

Method overriding is not possible in WCF you can only implement the method overloading  as explained in this posts.

Even I giving the code below for method overloading:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyCalculator
 {
        [OperationContract(Name="AddFloats")]
        float Add(float operand1, float operand2);

        [OperationContract(Name="AddIntegers")]
        int Add(int operand1,int operand2);
 }
```